# Selenium Webdriver Node js

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Puppeteer has connect function to  connect with existing browser instance but in selenium ,how to connect to a existing instance of IE browser using selenium(webdriver) in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because that function is for chromeDriver only

Comment: This should be a comment. It's only a simple sentence.